Unable to send messages via React frontend and POST requests fail on Django REST API panel
I am building a chat application using React for the frontend and Django for the backend. I am facing the following two issues:

Issue with sending messages in React:
When I try to send a message through the React app, I receive a 400 Bad Request error. The API request is made to the backend using a POST request, but the response indicates that there was a problem. The error message doesn't provide much insight, and I cannot send the message.

Issue with POST request in Django REST API panel:
When I try to make a POST request from the Django REST framework interface (admin panel) to send a chat message, the request seems to go through successfully but redirects to a blank page (without an error). The data is not posted, and nothing changes on the frontend. However, when I use curl to send the same request, it works fine.


Here’s a snippet of the relevant React code for sending messages:
const handleSendMessage = async () => {
    if (message.trim() || file) {
        setSendingMessage(true);
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('receiver', selectedContact.id);
        formData.append('content', message);
        if (file) formData.append('file', file);

        try {
            const response = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/chat/${userData?.current_basic_user?.username}/`, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`,
                },
                body: formData,
            });
            
            if (!response.ok) {
                console.error('Failed to send message:', response.statusText);
            }
            const responseData = await response.json();
            setChatHistory((prevMessages) => [...prevMessages, responseData]);
            setMessage('');
            setFile(null);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error sending message:", error);
        } finally {
            setSendingMessage(false);
        }
    }
};

And here's the backend code for the POST request:
class ChatSingleView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    parser_classes = [MultiPartParser, FormParser]  # To handle file uploads

    def get(self, request, username):
        try:
            # Get the current user's profile
            current_basic_user = request.user
            current_basic_user_profile = BasicUserProfile.objects.get(user=current_basic_user)

            # Get the receiver profile by username
            receiver_user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            receiver_profile = BasicUserProfile.objects.get(user=receiver_user)

            # Get the chat history between the current user and receiver
            chat_history_feed = Chat.objects.filter(
                sender=current_basic_user_profile, reciever=receiver_profile
            ) | Chat.objects.filter(
                sender=receiver_profile, reciever=current_basic_user_profile
            )

            # Serialize the chat history
            chat_serializer = ChatSerializer(chat_history_feed, many=True)

            # Return the chat history in response
            return Response({
                "chat_history_feed": chat_serializer.data
            }, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return Response({"error": "Receiver profile or chat history not found."}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        except Exception as e:
            return Response({"error": f"An unexpected error occurred: {str(e)}"}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)

    def post(self, request, username):
        try:
            # Get the current authenticated user's profile
            current_basic_user = request.user
            current_basic_user_profile = BasicUserProfile.objects.get(user=current_basic_user)

            # Get the receiver profile based on username
            receiver_user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            receiver_profile = BasicUserProfile.objects.get(user=receiver_user)

            # Extract content and receiver ID from request data
            content = request.data.get("content")
            receiver_id = request.data.get("receiver")  # This is the receiver id sent from frontend

            # Log received values for debugging
            print(f"Received content: {content}, receiver_id: {receiver_id}, file: {request.FILES.get('file')}")

            # Ensure required fields are present
            if not content or not receiver_id:
                return Response({"error": "Content and receiver are required."}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

            # Validate the receiver ID - this might need to match the profile id
            if receiver_profile.id != int(receiver_id):
                return Response({"error": "Receiver ID mismatch."}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

            # Handle the file upload (optional)
            file = request.FILES.get("file", None)

            # Create the chat message instance
            chat_message = Chat(
                sender=current_basic_user_profile,
                reciever=receiver_profile,
                content=content,
                creation_date=timezone.now().date(),  # Ensure it's just the date part
                file=file
            )

            # Save the chat message
            chat_message.save()

            # Serialize and return the created chat message
            chat_serializer = ChatSerializer(chat_message)
            return Response(chat_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return Response({"error": "Receiver profile not found."}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        except Exception as e:
            # Log the exception message
            print(f"Unexpected error: {str(e)}")
            return Response({"error": f"An unexpected error occurred: {str(e)}"}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)

What I’ve tried:

I checked the request headers and data and they seem correct.
I have successfully posted messages using curl, so the API itself works fine.
I ensured the correct token is sent in the request headers.
I verified that the backend is properly handling the POST request.

Any insights on why this is happening or what I might be missing?
Thank you for your help!

Did you try it from postman?

Check the network tab in developer tools of browser and see if there are any CORS error that are blocking your request to backend
